# How to set a single cell to both number and bold format with Python/XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have formatted a column as a number that is not bolded. I want the grand total value/cell only for that column to then be formatted as a number and bolded

Code below formats the entire column as number (which is fine) but also bolds the entire column, but only want the last cell of the column bolded. Tried multiple ways to accomplish this but all not syntaically allowed. Ex: there is no "worksheet1.set_cell"

```
# Set format for accounting
Acct = workbook.add_format()
Acct.set_num_format(0x2c)
worksheet1.set_column('N:N', 12, Acct) 

AcctBold = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 0x2c, 'bold': True})
worksheet1.set_column('N200:N200', 12, AcctBold) #bolds the entire column
```

Goal: final cell for column N is formated as accounting and is bolded.The rest of the column is not bolded

Answer (score 0):

The [`set_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column) method sets properties for an entire column. If you want to set data for a cell use [`write()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write):

```
worksheet1.write('N200', 12, AcctBold)
```

Comment: Thx. I was thinking since I had already written the cell I would lose the previous value (a formula) by writing to it again - which is what happened. But I modified to  worksheet1.write('N200', 12, myformula, AcctBold) and it solved my issue. Much appreciated